# MIgrate to drupal 7 join related tables

Tags: 7, migrations

I am migrating from a another non Drupal CMS. I have 4 tables:

- stories (story1, story2, story3)
- story_tags (story_id, tag_id)
- tags (ABC, NBC, WTOP, CBS, clinton)
- tag_types (radio, tv, person)

How can I link tags to stories by `tag_type`. So that when I open a story I can see all it's related tags, knowing that a story can have several tags.
Any good detailed tutorial of migrate module link will be appreciated also.

**update**
How can i translate this in a migrate query

```
SELECT t.name FROM tags t 
    join tag_types tt on (tt.id = 3)
    join story_tags stg on (stg.tag_id = t.id) WHERE story_id = $row_id'
```

Tried but it is not working:

```
->select('story_tags', 'tags')
->fields('tags', array('tag_id'))
->leftJoin('tag_types', 'tt', '(tt.id = tag.tag_type_id)')
->condition('tag_type_id', '3', '=' )
->condition('story_id', $row->id, '=')
->execute()
->fetchCol();
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this would be to have a content type called `Story` that had 2 taxonomy term references. One tag field could just be called `tags` and then other could be called `tag_types`. These 2 fields would be 2 distinct Taxonomy Vocabularies in Drupal.

Drupal 7 actually installs with a `tags` vocabulary out-of-the-box which is assumed to be free-tagging terms as your legacy site appears to be already using. So you just need to make 1 vocabulary for the `tag_types`.

Anyways then in your migration class for Stories. Your source SQL statement would figure out the necessary terms for these 2 fields, probably using a sub-select, and the migrate module can set the terms for the content type as Stories are inserted into the system.

So, some psuedocode is:

```
<?php

class StoryMigration extends Migration
{
  public function __construct($arguments)
  {
    parent::__construct($arguments);
    $query = Database::getConnection('default', 'legacy')
      ->select('stories')
      ->fields('stories', array('pgid', 'page_title', 'page_body'));
    // Create subqueries to get the tags for the story we are on. We will call
    // a fake field in our SQL query as legacy_tags or legacy_tags_type to be
    // passed using Migrate field mappings.
    $query->addExpression('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(term_name) FROM legacydb_terms WHERE page_id = pgid' ,'legacy_tags');
    $query->addExpression('SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(term_name) FROM legacydb_term_types WHERE page_id = pgid' ,'legacy_tags_type');
    $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);
    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('page');

    $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
      array(
        'pgid' => array('type' => 'int',
          'unsigned' => TRUE,
          'not null' => TRUE,
          'description' => t('Source ID'),
        )
      ),
      MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema()
    );

    $this->addFieldMapping('title', 'page_title');
    $this->addFieldMapping('body', 'page_body');

    // Import a story's tag(s). Make the term in the vocabulary if it's not
    // there already, ignore the CaSe of the term so sloppy legacy terms
    // come across as 1 term.
    // By specifying this could have a SEPERATOR VALUE this can create any N
    // terms provided by our SQL statement above.
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_tags', 'legacy_tags');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_tags:create_term')
      ->defaultValue(TRUE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_tags:ignore_case')
      ->defaultValue(TRUE);

    // Similar steps as for the above term, but for the tags_type reference field.
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_tags_type', 'legacy_tags_type');
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_tags_type:create_term')
      ->defaultValue(TRUE);
    $this->addFieldMapping('field_tags_type:ignore_case')
      ->defaultValue(TRUE);
  }
}
```

[Term Reference Fields and the Migrate module are described in the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1224042). [Adding SQL Expressions to an SQL query](https://www.drupal.org/node/1848358) is covered in the sql documentation.

My above code is an example and not guarenteed to work. It's simply 1 method of doing this and is to be referenced as an outline. Your SQL schema and php may look different in the end.

Comment: Thanks, I added an update. Do you know how to fix the query?